# change a laravel collection format for dropdown

Tags: laravel, data-structures, collections, toarray

With Laravel, I generate my list of object like that:

```
return Federation::lists('name','id');
```

So, this returns me [1 => 'elt1', 2 => 'elt2'] , etc

What I need is transform it to:

```
[{value => 1, text => 'elt1'},{value => 2, text => 'elt2'}]
```

is it a way to do it??

Answer (score 1):

You can probably write your own collection class with a custom `toCustomArray` method inside.

```php
class YourCollection extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {
   public function toCustomArray() {
      // Your own implementation goes here. 
   }
}
```

Refresh your cache afterwards. Now you would be able to do:

```php
Federation::pluck('name', 'id')->toCustomArray();
```

**TL;DR**

The `lists` method is deprecated since Laravel 5.2. Instead please use the `pluck()` method, optionally with a `toArray()` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can map through the collection and manipulate it

```
$array = $collection->map(function($item){
    return ["value" => $item->id, "text" => $item->name];
});

$json = json_encode($array);
```